# Jquery Slideshowify with hyperlink to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am using `Slideshowify` in my webpage and want a hyperlink on top of it (aligned at center position), so that on clicking the text, user is redirected to another page. With each image a different text will be shown.

Below is the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#slideshow a img').slideshowify();
});
```

```css
.spanstyle
{
  text-align:center; 
  color:#FFF; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subchild/jquery.slideshowify.js/master/js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subchild/jquery.slideshowify.js/master/js/jquery.slideshowify.min.js"></script>

<div id="slideshow">
            <a href="https://www.google.com"> <span class="spanstyle"> Image 1 </span> <img alt="image1" src="http://www.wallpaperandphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/summer_landscape-wallpaper-2560x1600.jpg" style="display: none;"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com"> <span class="spanstyle"> Image 2 </span> <img alt="image2" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcST9Gcz3vT0LeZpIa6Ch71scJbUY81HjIvKJ5EhbMDxMh9mSLxi" style="display: none;"/></a>
            <a href="https://www.jsfiddle.net"> <span class="spanstyle"> Image 3 </span> <img alt="image3" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEg2QvjFNxO7o7KYQb-g5PS_5Y7MK4Oz3G2xapGQKeNetZMVHs" style="display: none;"/></a>
        </div>
```

Here all the hyperlink texts are shown together in every image and is not aligned to center. What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will helps to align hypertext in center of the div. Please adjust this width according to your link text

```
#slideshow
    {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 172px;
    }
```

Comment: This aligns the text only horizontally and not vertically. Also, only one hyperlink per image shall be shown. Right now, all the hyperlinks are shown with every image.

Comment: Your js fiddle is not perfect. if dont mine Please provide your working url ?

Comment: I am trying to create something like [this](http://gooyaabitemplates.com/livepreview/memento-creative/). Please check. Hope this helps.